# How does next() method on iterators work?

Tags: java, iterator

I have a doubt with the `next()` method on iterators.  If I have as a part of my code this lines (with `arrayOfStrings` size = 4):

```
Iterator<String> it = arrayOfStrings.iterator(); //arrayOfString is ArrayList<String>

while(it.hasNext()) {
    String e = it.next();
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

At the very first iteration, the iterator starts pointing to element with index 0? or like the "index -1" ?

I ask because as far as I know the `next()` method returns the next element in the collection.

So, if at the very first iteration the iterator starts at index 0 when `next()` is invoked, it returns the element at index 1 and I won´t be able to do nothing with the element at index 0?

Comment: The code you show should correctly print **all elements** of the `ArrayList`. The `it.next()` call will, at its first call, also return the **first element**. This element is usually denoted with **index 0**.

Comment: Did you know you can look at the source code of java classes to see what they do and how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ways to iterate over a List in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410035/ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-java)

Comment: Think of iterator as a cursor when you are typing text, imagine you had "abc" in some text file, and you want to read each and every one of those letters, at the very beginning cursor will be just before letter 'a' when you call next imagine that it moves one place to the right and selects the element it moves over, so you can now print that element or do something with it, then on the next call it will move over across 'b' so you can do something with 'b', and it keeps doing this until it has nothing to move over.

Comment: @user1803551 OP is not asking how to iterate over a List - OP is asking about the mechanics of iterating using `next()` and, specifically, the edge case when fetching the first element.

Comment: @ochi The question is not what determines duplicate, it's the answers. The answers there address this.

Comment: @user1803551 I'll agree to disagree ;)

Comment: IMO this is a reasonable question - it's asking how to model where and when an iterator points (i.e. is it pointing "in between", "before", or something else?)

Comment: It's all about the documentation as it just says *"returns the next element"*. Technically *next* implies that there was already something before. So in my opinion it is reasonable to ask what the first element is. The documentation could have explained this better.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth And that is shown well in the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html), with a diagram, code examples and explanation. Questions which do not do research are not good questions and this is even a good downvote reason.

Comment: @user1803551 - Point taken.  But bear in mind that's a tutorial page for `List`, so not necessarily what you'd stumble upon if you're researching the semantics of iterators in general.  And as Zabuza points out, the language in the Javadoc isn't necessarily helpful.

Comment: @ochi Maybe you'd prefer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194702/cursor-implementation-in-iterator-in-java-collections

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think of `next` as a two-step process. First it gets the next item in the iterator, then it increments the pointer to point to the next item. So, when you create a new iterator, it is initialized to return the first item (index 0) in your list.

Answer (score 6):

My way to imagine the way iterators work is to think about it as the thing that is placed **between** the indexes. So when the first `next()` is being called you can return the value stored under the [0] index and after that call, iterator waits between index [0] and [1] for the next call to return for you value stored at index [1]. After the second `next()` call iterator waits between [1] and [2] and so on...

It is just my way to get used to iterators but it might be helpful for you some way.

Answer (score 2):

The code you show will correctly print **all elements** of the `ArrayList`. The `it.next()` call will, at its first call, also the **first element**. This element is usually denoted with **index 0**.

Note that you might want to rename `arrayOfStrings` as technically it's no **array**, it's more a `List`. A user might due the name think that it is an array.

---

### Documentation

In my opinion you are right that the [documentation of the method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--) can be a bit confusing since it is so compact:

> Returns the next element in the iteration.

However the description probably needs to be so undetailed since `Iterator` is a very frequently used interface, not only for collections. I could imagine a class where the *first iteration element* should not be the first element of the underlying structure. For example some kind of stream that was already read until a given point. So basically it is up to the implementing class to decide what the *first element* is. But for collections it will truly be the **first element** (index 0).

---

### For-each

Also note that the iteration you show is equivalent to how the **extended for-loop** (for-each) works in Java. So a syntax like

```
for (Item item : items) {
    ...
}
```

will be treated like

```
Iterator<Item> iter = items.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    Item item = iter.next();
    ...
}
```

In fact this is the reason why you can use everything that implements `Iterable` in *extended for loops*.

Knowing this it would rather be confusing if `iter.next()` would skip the first element. I mean by the name **for-each** is supposed to iterate **all** elements.

---

### Insights

Let's take a closer look at how the method is implemented. Therefore we will first see what `ArrayList#iterator` does. Take a look at its [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList):

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr();
}
```

The `Itr` class is a private class of `ArrayList` ([source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.Itr)). And [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.Itr.next%28%29) is the `Itr#next` method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public E next() {
    checkForComodification();
    int i = cursor;
    if (i >= size)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

    Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
    if (i >= elementData.length)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();

    cursor = i + 1;
    return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
}
```

So what it essentially returns is the element at index `i` which is where the cursor was at the point of calling the method. It also already advances the cursor by one for the next call of the method.

The cursor however is implicitly initialized with `0` due to:

```
int cursor; // Default value for int is 0
```

So the first call of `next` will indeed return the element at index `0` which is the **first element**.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. But I can't see from the `Itr#next`method code you provided here where the cursor and size parameters are coming from? How these parameters are passed here?

Comment: The iterator comes from the arraylist, it remembers the current index as field internally.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain this with `ListIterator` which has both `next` and `previous`. `next` has same concept in both `Iterator` and `ListIterator`

```
ListIterator<String> itr = linkedList.listIterator();
```

Here `itr` will point at first index (index=0)

Think `next` as "current" and `previous` as "previous".

That means,

`itr.hasNext()` = returns true if `itr` has any element at current position.

`itr.next()` = return the current element and move `itr` to next position.

`itr.hasPrevious()` = returns true if there is any element at position before `itr`.

`itr.previous()` = move the `itr` to previous element and return that element.